# Does reading the Qur'an while alone attract jinn?

Tags: jinn

I used to recite The Holy Quran all the night in a room, doors closed, at our house, for the whole night until the time of Fajr prayer. My parents stopped me from doing so. The reason behind their worry is that they think a person reciting Holy Quran alone, in the dark, is more likely to be attacked by a Jinn.

is there any evidence from Quran and sunnah that a person is more likely to attract jinn if they isolate themselves when they read Quran and do zikr?

Comment: not trying to be offensive or anything why would you sit in the dark and do so? it kind of creeps me out too

Comment: Have you ever asked them about the basis of this saying?

Comment: Not _totally_ dark

Comment: Don't be afraid of jinns. Some of them are good. Even the bad ones are not monsters that attack you in dark, like you see in the horror movies.

Answer (score 4):

We would require **very strong** evidence to forbid you from reciting the quran in the night in a dark room. BUT if your parents have a problem with the dark room, you can always light it up more so that their hearts are at ease.

**Attacks from Satan**

If you do good, they will distract and attack you anyways. I would strongly disagree with anyone who restricts any good with the fear of being attacked by the satan or jinns.

**How to protect yourself**

**Recite surah falaq** in which we ask Allah protection from the "mischief of the darkness"

**Recite surah naas** in which we ask Allah protection from the "retreating whisperer....from among men and jinn"

Both these suras will Insha Allah protect you...

**Some hadith to support night ibaadaah**

> Bukhari Volume 2, Book 21, Number 246 :
>   Narrated by Abu Huraira
>   Allah's Apostle (p.b.u.h) said, "Our Lord, the Blessed, the Superior, comes every night down on the nearest Heaven to us when the last third of the night remains, saying: "Is there anyone to invoke Me, so that I may respond to invocation? Is there anyone to ask Me, so that I may grant him his request? Is there anyone seeking My forgiveness, so that I may forgive him?"

**Some personal advice: Get some sleep too....**

If you have other commitments, please do not over pressure yourself . Even the Prophet(pbuh) used to sleep.

PLS Remember ... I am not stopping you to pray the full night, rather only advising.

> Bukhari Volume 2, Book 21, Number 247 :
>   Narrated by Al-Aswad
>   I asked 'Aisha "How is the night prayer of the Prophet?" She replied, "He used to sleep early at night, and get up in its last part to pray, and then return to his bed. When the Muadh-dhin pronounced the Adhan, he would get up. If he was in need of a bath he would take it; otherwise he would perform ablution and then go out (for the prayer)."

The Prophet(pbuh) would "sleep early", so he would balance his sleep.

Comment: Do you know of anything in the texts specifically about jinn approaching a solitary reciter of the Qur'an in the dark or at night?

Comment: surah falak points to "mischief in the darkness". solitary or not.....no there is nothing I am aware of, but they will attack anyways, thats their job. We would still need really strong evidence to stop someone from reciting the quran.

Comment: I once learnt The Holy Quran by heart - i was a Hafiz-e-Quran - but in the past 4 years i forgot a major portion of This Holy Book. I cannot sleep at nights or rest in days with such a guilt on my head. I've been to doctor thrice in the last two months because of less sleep and overworking, but i just can't sleep well with such a sin on my hands.

Answer (score 4):

Based on verses **46:29** and **72:1**, once some of the jinn were listening to the Prophet's(PBUH) recitation of Qur'an:

> وَإِذْ صَرَ‌فْنَا إِلَيْكَ نَفَرً‌ا مِّنَ الْجِنِّ يَسْتَمِعُونَ الْقُرْ‌آنَ فَلَمَّا حَضَرُ‌وهُ قَالُوا أَنصِتُوا ۖ فَلَمَّا قُضِيَ وَلَّوْا إِلَىٰ قَوْمِهِم مُّنذِرِ‌ينَ
>
> And [mention, O Muhammad], when We directed to you a few of the jinn, listening to the Qur'an. And when they attended it, they said, "Listen quietly." And when it was concluded, they went back to their people as warners.
>
> [Al-Ahqaf: 29](http://quran.com/46/29)
>
> قُلْ أُوحِيَ إِلَيَّ أَنَّهُ اسْتَمَعَ نَفَرٌ‌ مِّنَ الْجِنِّ فَقَالُوا إِنَّا سَمِعْنَا قُرْ‌آنًا عَجَبًا
>
> Say, [O Muhammad], "It has been revealed to me that a group of the jinn listened and said, 'Indeed, we have heard an amazing Qur'an.
>
> [Al-Jinn: 1](http://quran.com/72/1)

So your parent's thought may be somehow derived from these verses. But I think according to the following verse of Surat Al-Jinn, there should be no worry about them while doing so:

> (The Jinns said:)
>
> وَأَنَّا لَمَّا سَمِعْنَا الْهُدَىٰ آمَنَّا بِهِ ۖ فَمَن يُؤْمِن بِرَ‌بِّهِ فَلَا يَخَافُ بَخْسًا وَلَا رَ‌هَقًا
>
> And when we heard the guidance, we believed in it. And whoever believes in his Lord will not fear deprivation or burden.
>
> [Al-Jinn: 13](http://quran.com/72/13)

I also suggest that you have a look at [these](http://quran.com/72/1-15) verses of Surat Al-Jinn as well.